# Cocommutative bimonads: Why does this diagram commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories, hopf-algebras, monads

**1. Definitions**
Let $(C, \otimes,I, a, l,r,c)$ be a monoidal category with braiding $c:\otimes \rightarrow\otimes ^{op}$. Let $(S,\mu,\eta,\tau,\theta)$ be a bimonad on $C$.
Following Turaev and Virelizier in *Monoidal Categories and Topological Field Theory* we define a bimonad as follows:

- $(S,\mu,\eta)$ is a monad on $C$ with multiplication $\mu$ and unit $\eta$.
- $(S, \tau,\theta)$ is an [oplax monoidal functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/oplax+monoidal+functor) with natural transformation $\tau: S \circ \otimes \Longrightarrow \otimes \circ (S,S)$ and morphism $\theta: S(I) \rightarrow I$.
- The multiplication $\mu$ and the unit $\eta$ are comonoidal natural transformations (that is monoidal natural transformations of the respective lax monoidal functors $C^{op} \rightarrow C^{op}$). Here we consider the oplax monoidal functor $(S^2, \tau \circ S(\tau), \theta \circ S(\theta))$ where $S(\tau)$ and $S(\theta)$ denote whiskered natural transformations.

Let $S$ be cocommutative, i.e. $c \circ \tau = \tau \circ S(c)$ holds.

**2. Problem**
I am trying to show that in the above setting the following diagram in $C$ commutes for all $X,Y \in Obj(C)$:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S(X \otimes X \otimes Y \otimes Y) @>{\tau_{X \otimes X, Y \otimes Y}}>> S(X \otimes X) \otimes S(Y \otimes Y)\\
@V{S(id_X \otimes c_{X,Y} \otimes id_Y)}VV @V{\tau_{X, X} \otimes \tau_{Y,Y}}VV \\
S(X \otimes Y \otimes X \otimes Y) @. S(X) \otimes S(X) \otimes S(Y) \otimes S(Y)\\ 
@V{\tau_{X \otimes Y, X \otimes Y}}VV @V{id_{S(X)}\otimes c_{S(X), S(Y)}\otimes id_{S(Y)}}VV \\
S(X \otimes Y) \otimes S(X \otimes Y) @>{\tau_{X, Y} \otimes \tau_{X, Y}}>> S(X) \otimes S(Y) \otimes S(X)
\otimes S(Y)
\end{CD}$$

The commutativity of this diagram seems similar to the cocommutativity of $S$. Informally: "Pulling tensor products out of $S$ and then braiding on the outside is the same as braiding on the inside and then pulling tensor factors out of $S$." I tried using the cocommutativity to write the above diagram as a composite of commuting diagrams (diagram chasing), however I keep getting more and more diagrams inside the one above without being able to connect all nodes.

**3. Questions**
Any ideas? Is there a type of graphical calculus I could use to tackle the problem?

Comment: There is a graphical calculus for lax monoidal functors: https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/papers/Mellies06csl.pdf let's see if it is possible to prove your equation there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just say that this diagram

[image]

commutes because

1. is just two different ways to "completely unpack" $S(XXYY)$
2. commutes because $S$ is natural at $c$
3. is your cocommutativity assumption
4. same as 1.

Comment: Great, thank you! That works.

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread, but ... How do you tackle such a problem? Do you "just see it" or do you have a more strategic approach?

Comment: You draw the outer boundary of the diagram: that's the claim, "this diagram commutes". Then you consider the "sink" or the "source" of it, i.e. the initial or the terminal vertex of it. Take the first two contiguous arrows: in what sensible commutative square do they fit? Do you have an axiom ensuring that a certain diagram having those two arrows as partial boundary commutes? Same question with the next two arrows; same question with the next two; piecewise, you "tile" the bigger diagram with polygons that you know are commutative and you know that the outer diagram also commutes.

Comment: as a teacher, I am very sad that this operational approach to category theory problem solving isn't openly taught to students, and it is considered "self-evident", yet you have to digest exercises on finding eigenvalues of matrices "ad nauseam", done in similar painstaking concreteness... this is one reason why people think CT is scary/abstruse.

Comment: That is indeed a pity. Your approach is quite useful, it helped me do a different diagram chase just now, thank you.